# AJAX call not going to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am using ajax to populate a drop down but the call is not going to the server. getting the following error in fire bug

> POST 0
>   status 404 not found

my code is:

```
function selectChildCategory(parent,child){
    var url = "<?php echo url::site('admin/video/showSubCategory/')?>";
    if(parent != "")
    {
            if(child != 0){
               url = url+parent+"/"+child;
            }else{
               url = url+parent+"/"+0;
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type:"POST",
                success: function(select)
                {
                    //alert(select);
                    $("#sub_category").html(select);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

the parammeters are showing correct values....but call is not going to the server. The URL is correct

please advise.

Comment: Please show the final, generated JavaScript code, not the PHP original. Is the call going to the same domain as the page this is in?

Comment: Try using firebug or equivalent to see where the request is made...

Comment: this is not the php code.... infact this is the javascript code..... also the page is in the same domain. also i am using firebug and it is showing post 0 and URL http://localhost/cmsk3/index.php/admin/video/showSubCategory/127/0

Comment: "this is not the php code.... infact this is the javascript code" There's your problem. Is the extension of the URL you are calling ".html" or ".php"?

Answer (score 1):

404 Error code means that the page your are trying to call does not exists.

You are buildng a HTTP path using your parent and child variables but if the formed url does not exists (or is not captured by any mod_rewrite) a 404 error is shown.

For example, for parent "0" and child "0" the url **/admin/video/showSubCategory/0/0** exists?

Also if you are using something like mod_rewrite is really correctly configured?

Try first calling the URL manually to check if the url generated by javascript really exists.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the URL is available via a POST request?